# How can I correct html for missing closing tags in c# ?

Tags: c#, web-development, web-applications

I have html stored in database received from text editors and because of some mistakes in the code the html is not valid, it is missing some closing tags. and due to this I am not able to process this html for some other operations like generating pdfs. So I need to write some code in c# that can check for tags that are missing closing tags and insert a closing tag at the correct place.

Comment: What does some of this bad html look like?  How will you know where the missing tag goes?

Comment: the bad html is something like `<td> <p> some text </td> `. See the  <p> tag is not closed and it is already saved in database. so when I am trying to parse this in code, I get an exception and code stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Morons that making the authors correct it is the best course. But if you need a technical solution you could punch it through htmltidy -- an old utility that, well, tidys up HTML code. There is [a well maintained managed version on github](https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged).

Comment: This library worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

**You are never going to know the intent of the author, don't waste your time trying.**

Validate the HTML on insert, and kick back a message to the user on Error.

*Or*

When i did this i used IE automation to interpret the HTML, so the UI where the user enters it can show the user how it will look (using the Local IE or browser they are currently using as the interpreter). IE is also very forgiving when interpreting HTML, so it doesn't have to be perfect. The key is that the user sees what it looks like before hand, and I can interpret the HTML in a way that matches what the user saw.

Comment: A more portable alternative to embedding IE is embedding the WebKit HTML engine. The Qt project includes an easy-to-use library for this task.

Comment: A slight variation on this is to embed a rendering engine in your pdf.  For example, [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) will generate pdfs that look pretty much the same as how the html would look if opened in Chrome.